# Dynamically Reload Spring Mongo Database Connection Without Restarting Server

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

We're deploying a spring-based webapp in Tomcat and we'd like to give the user an option of which mongo database to connect to.  To do this, we have a set-up wizard that captures the mongo connection details from the user through an online form.  After capturing these details, we'd like to dynamically connect to Mongo.  Right now we load our mongo via xml configuration:

```
<bean id="configmapper" class="com.db.util.ConfigurationMapper" />
<bean id="configmap" factory-bean="configmapper" factory-method="readXML" />
<mongo:mongo host="#{configmap.getHost()}" port="#{configmap.getPort()}" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="#{configmap.getName()}"
    mongo-ref="mongo" />
```

The user values are stored read/written by the config mapper bean, but after setting them, we want to basically "restart" the mongo driver.  To do this we are trying:

```
XmlWebApplicationContext context = ((XmlWebApplicationContext) ContextLoader
            .getCurrentWebApplicationContext());
context.refresh();
```

This has the nice result of reloading all of our applciation beans, and we can even see the Mongo beans re-created in the log along with all the other beans in the context:

```
DEBUG 2015-05-12 21:09:29,590 [http-nio-8087-exec-6] (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mongo'
...
DEBUG 2015-05-12 21:09:08,121 [localhost-startStop-1] (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mongoTemplate'
...
DEBUG 2015-05-12 21:09:29,590 [http-nio-8087-exec-6] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:449) - Creating instance of bean 'mongoDbFactory'
```

However, when we go to use the connection, we get the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
    at org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:367)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:622)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:936)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:914)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:858)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2069)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2053)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1828)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1645)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:560)
```

We thought perhaps the mongo connection wasn't properly being closed so we brought in our mongo bean and closed it before reloading:

```
@Autowired
private Mongo mongo;
...
mongo.close();
XmlWebApplicationContext context = ((XmlWebApplicationContext) ContextLoader
                .getCurrentWebApplicationContext());
context.refresh();
```

But we receive the same exception.

Does anyone know how we can go about achieving dynamic mongo reconnection without restarting our app server?  Perhaps there is another way to go about this problem?  We'd like to provide the end-user with a GUI web config as opposed to having to edit the config file themselves.

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this ? Were you able to dynamically reload the Spring-Data-Mongodb successfully ?

Comment: I have not been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when accessing the database from the spring application context. After days worth of investigation i finally figured out that there was a timing issue and introducing a delay after setting the database credentials and before reload the context again solved the issue. For some reason my reloading of the context was being done too early and the database settings were not yet set at the time it tried to reload.

Once the delay was introduced, everything started working as expected.

I hope it helps.